# process.start doesn't work in Azure web role

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to open a new window from a web role(Azure). But `Process.start` doesn't work and it isn't throwing any exceptions

```
Process.Start(url);
```

Comment: well what computer did you expect it to run on?

Comment: It's a windows live redirect url for importing contacts.

https://consent.live.com/Delegation.aspx?ps=Contacts.View&ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.cloudsponge.com%2Fauth&pl=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.cloudsponge.com%2Fpolicy&app=appid%3D000000004802FD29%26ts%3D1332850961%26sig%3DGifl3tKNND3c0mSyIlOY%252FvZuu8kDD4Cv5o4wHQpvBj4%253D%250A&appctx=%7B%22custID%22:%226e90e99ea8e345813de5003bcbc25ef20162cbb5%22,%22id%22:6132840%7D <https://consent.live.com/Delegation.aspx?ps=Contacts.View&ru=https://api.cloudsponge.com/auth&pl=https://api.cloudsponge.com/policy&app=appid%3D000000004802FD29%26ts%3D1332850961%26sig....

Comment: I have you are not expecting some window to open on client side. Enable Azure Diagnostics to see if there are any exceptions being logged.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't make sense. Unless you are logged into the machine and run it you will never see what Process.Start does.

Considering you are looking at ASP.NET are you looking for something more like

```
Response.Redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start("http://consent.live.com/bla-bla-bla") should try to execute IE to complete this request in Windows Azure VM, but i'm afraid it will not work without active session, however i may be wrong.

Anyway, if you want to make this request on the server side it is better to use something like this:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.GetResponse();
```